# R GraphNEL: Result of adj function is a vector of length one. Access concatenated values separately?

Tags: r, random

Im working with a graphNEL object and need to extract the adjacent nodes of
a specified node. This is solvable with adj(nodes(graph),"node123"),
however the nodes are returned as a vector of size 1. So I cant
access directly vertain nodes for it.

Lets say:

```
> adjacent <- adj(subgraph,"hsa:991")
> adjacent
$`hsa:991`
[1] "hsa:10744" "hsa:29945" "hsa:51433" "hsa:8881"
```

For an algorithm I just need lets say "hsa:29945" but since this
vector just is of size one, I have a problem. Is this possible? 
The best thing would be that every node is recognized as a element.
Btw.: maybe somebody can explain to me why they are even only one element
I mean [1] "hsa:10744 hsa:29945 hsa:51433 hsa:8881" I could understand
but why are there quotes after every node? After all I just need to implement
a random walk on a graph. But I havent found any packages. So I will try to
implement it myself.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers 
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adj(g, index=XXX)` is returning a list containing the neighbours for each entry of XXX.
So, in order to extract the results for an entry of XXX you need to access the corresponding entry in the list. This then gives you the desired results:

```
##a simple mock-up graph
g <- new("graphNEL", nodes=c("V1","V2","V3"), edgemode="undirected")
g <- addEdge("V1","V2",g)
g <- addEdge("V1","V3",g)

adj.res <- adj(g,"V1") #returns a list
adj.res[["V1"]] #returns a vector
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your example returns a vector of size one. But I want to access the specific nodes.

Comment: I think I don't get your request :-)
When calling
`length(adj.res[["V1"]]) #returns a vector
[1] 2`
This gives a vector of size 2, containing the entries
`[1] "V2" "V3"`
If I store this in a vector I can access all elements, thereby giving me the neighbouring nodes of V1, where I can e.g. access the second element:
`> res <- adj.res[["V1"]] #returns a vector
> res[2]
[1] "V3"`